# What measurement should I take to buy an atmospheric filter for my espresso machine?

Tags: espresso-machine, filter

I want to buy an atmospheric filter for my espresso machine, but I don't know what part of the filter I should measure. Should I be measuring the radius from the internal part of the border of the filter or the external part of the ring/border?

Sorry, I tried to express myself as well as I could but I am not familiar with some coffee terminology in English.

Comment: Welcome! You could add a _picture_ - that often helps when words don’t.

Comment: @Stephie Ok. I will when I have more time and I'll add the machine's name as well.

Comment: i've never heard of atmospheric filters for espresso machines - what's that supposed to do?

Comment: @ths Maybe it isn't called that way in english. It's the same as non presurized filter.

Comment: i think you might mean "non pressurized portafilter" or "basket". https://wokelark.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/dual_wall_and_single_wall_basket_top_and_bottom.png

Answer (score 1):

The portafilter sizes are given as the *inner diameter* of the basket in mm. This is the same as the diameter a tight fitting tamper would have.